# Get intermidiate results in a for loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph

I have the following code that generate a graph  from a matrix `adj` and a set of nodes stored in `nodeNames`. I have two types of nodes : `i` node of type S and `j` node of type O . in `nodeNames` the nodes of type O are stored first , so from `nodeNames{1}` to `nodeNames{j}` are allocated to nodes O .

```
G = digraph(adj,nodeNames);
for x=1:j 
    v = dfsearch(G,nodeNames{x});
end
```

the following code allows me to search for all the `dfsearch` results for nodes of type O, but in this way I only get the last result in the display , I want to get all the intermidiate itterations of the for loop . What is the best way to do that ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In generally the lengths of the vectors returned by `dfsearch` are not going to all be the same length, so `v` should be store in a cell array using `x` as the index:

```
G = digraph(adj,nodeNames);
for x=1:j 
    v{x} = dfsearch(G,nodeNames{x});
end
```

Comment: You should get a `1 x j` cell array with the results of each call to `dfsearch` in its own cell. Be sure you don't have `v` still hanging around in your workspace by doing `clear v`.